# Change the duplicates with the unique one's Values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to replace the **duplicated** value with the unique one's value.For example,
Let us take a **dataframe** `df`,

```
col1 col2
A     1
B     2
C     2
A     3
A     4
```

In this **col1** has duplicates of A with different or same values in **col2**.What i want is to replace the the duplicates with the value of unique one's **col2** like below,

```
col1 col2
A     1
B     2
C     2
A     1
A     1
```

Please help me sort out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So need repalce all duplicates by `1` values or by first value of duplicate - because first value of `A` is `1`, then repalced all values by `1` ?

Comment: @jezrael because first value of A is 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by Series created by removed duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].map(df.drop_duplicates('col1').set_index('col1')['col2'])
```

Another idea is use [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) - copy first value of group to all values of each group:

```
df['col2'] = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform('first')
```

---

```
print (df)
  col1  col2
0    A     1
1    B     2
2    C     2
3    A     1
4    A     1
```

EDIT:

If need replace all duplicates rows by `col1` in `col2` to `1`:

```
df.loc[df['col1'].duplicated(keep=False), 'col2'] = 1
print (df)
  col1  col2
0    A     1
1    B     2
2    C     2
3    A     1
4    A     1
```

Difference best seen in in changed data:

```
print (df)
  col1  col2
0    A     5
1    B     4
2    C     2
3    A     3
4    C     4

df['col2'] = df['col1'].map(df.drop_duplicates('col1').set_index('col1')['col2'])
print (df)
  col1  col2
0    A     5
1    B     4
2    C     2
3    A     5
4    C     2

df.loc[df['col1'].duplicated(keep=False), 'col2'] = 1
print (df)
  col1  col2
0    A     1
1    B     4
2    C     1
3    A     1
4    C     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace values where column1 is duplicated with 1 else with column2 values.

```
>>> df['col2'] = pd.np.where(df['col1'].duplicated(), 1, df['col2'])
```